# Questions pertaining to knowing an instrument

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask a question regarding how to use a particular instrument i.e some of the controls of my electric guitar. Will this question be off-topic ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be on topic.

Here is an example:

[What do the 2 “push/pull” knobs on my guitar do?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10253/what-do-the-2-push-pull-knobs-on-my-guitar-do)

Also, you can ask about controls on your amp. Like for example:

[Difference between pre and post gain](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15904/difference-between-pre-and-post-gain)